# summation (sigma) in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

How can I get

```
Ʃ 2^n
```

in via a formula in a cell in Excel, for n from 1 to N when N is a value in a neighbouring cell? I had a look at some related questions here, tried around and ended up with this here, which does not work (generates `#NAME?`). Can anybody correct this and explain?

```
=SUMPRODUCT(POW(2,ROW(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("1:",L41)))))
```

EDIT: omg, it's the `POW` which doesn't exist in Excel, should be `POWER`, how embarrassing. I always stumble across this, coming from C/C++. I thought the problem has to be somewhere in the other functions I never used before. Thanks anyways. I keep the question online though, maybe it is helpful to somebody.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(2^ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,A1)))
```

where **A1** holds *N*

[image]

See:

[Previous Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48210735/variable-length-series)

Answer (score 2):

I still would like to remark that `Ʃ 2^n` for 1 upto N is `2^(N+1) - 2`

```
=2^(L41+1)-2
=POWER(2, L41+1)-2
```

That is the `POWER` function or the `^` operator will do nicely.

`BITLSHIFT` for 2^N might not work always (floating point, Excel 2010).

Comment: `Ʃ 2^n` for 1 upto n would be (for n = 4) `2^1+2^2+2^3+2^4 = 2+4+8+16 = 30`. `2^(n+1) - 2 = 2^5 - 2 = 32 - 2 = 30`. But I almost think you want something else, inspecting a range of cells?

Comment: Sorry, @JoopEggen it seems like I deleted my question right when you typed your answer, since I then realized what you mean. However, I noticed that your formulas seem not to work, as they always return `2`, regardless of N. Imo, the correct formulas for what you're proposing should simply be `=POWER(2,L41+1)-2` (or `=2^(L41+1)-2`).

Comment: I admit, I copied the original (now changed) expression, not understanding a bit. I'll correct my answer, as it certainly improves legibility.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your remark, I didn't think of that. It is a lot more elegant in my case indeed and that's helping on another front of my work. The initial question was about summation in Excel in general though, for that reason I will mark Gary'sStudent's reply as the answer here.

Comment: Fine, I do not need the points, and I answered because of the unneeded summation: `Ʃi=0,n  2^n = 2^(n+1) - 1`.